# dynamic page creation - using JavaScript to change element attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms, gsp

I'm New to JavaSscript. I have a Java app, it displays a jsp which is a simple web form (actually a gsp, it's Groovy based). The gsp iterates through some Java objects (the form 'questions') and displays the relevant HTML element on the page according to the POJO's type (eg 'textfield', or 'radiogroup' etc). A bit like:

```
javaObjectsMap.foreach
    if(object.type == 'textfield')
        <input="text" id="object.id">
    if(object.type == 'radiogroup')
        <input="radio" id="object.id">
    ...etc etc.
```

The problem I have is that I want to change the border color of any textbox to red if that question has an error. I can test for the error fine (using a Grails `<g:if>` tag), and I can use the following to *manually* change the border of an element - but only if I hard-code the ID of the element:

```
document.getElementById(myElementId).style.borderColor="#FF0000"
```

Is there a way I can find `myElementId` at runtime? I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (say 'error') to the input field, if the field has error and give css style for class 'error'.